# Debug grails 3 app in IntelliJ Idea 15 CE fails

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I'm trying to debug a grails 3.1.0.M2 plugin using IntelliJ Idea 15 (Community Edition).  I created the project by simply importing the directory where the grails app lives.

Executing the grade task `bootRun` from within the IDE works fine.  I try to debug by loading the file `grails-app/init/grails/platform/core3/Application.groovy` into an editor pane, right-clicking and selecting `Debug 'Application.main()'`.  It then says

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51822,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/Users/u1cc13/Library/Caches/IdeaIC15/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/u1cc13/src/grails/grails-platform-core3/build/classes/main:/Users/u1cc13/src/grails/grails-platform-core3/build/resources/main:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" grails.platform.core3.Application
objc[35844]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51822', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51822', transport: 'socket'
Error: Could not find or load main class grails.platform.core3.Application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Hrumph!  So then I try to just run within the IDE and this tells me a bit more.  Right-click and select `Run 'Application.main()'`:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE EAP.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/u1cc13/src/grails/grails-platform-core3/build/classes/main:/Users/u1cc13/src/grails/grails-platform-core3/build/resources/main:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain grails.platform.core3.Application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/boot/config/GrailsAutoConfiguration
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm assuming the inability to "find or load main class grails.platform.core3.Application" in the first case is due to the missing GrailsAutoConfiguration class in the second case.

I'm an IntelliJ novice, so my guess is that I have a configuration problem in my project.  I've been through all of the project settings and everything looks OK to my (newbie) eye.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: npskirk, simply brilliant--it works like a charm!  If you want to convert this to answer, I will happily mark it as correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA lets you run a gradle target with both the run and the debug commands.

Since a Grails 3 project is just a gradle build, debugging the `bootRun` target should hook up the debugger to the running grails app.

Answer (score 0):

[Grails](https://grails.org/) is "[an open source web application framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_(framework)) that uses the Groovy programming language (which is in turn based on the Java platform)". [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) is "[an open source build automation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) that builds upon the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven and introduces a Groovy-based domain-specific language (DSL) [...]". Support for one does not imply support for the other.

IntelliJ IDEA has support for Gradle, both in the Community Edition and the Ultimate Edition. Support for Grails is officially only available in the Ultimate Edition; there might be some functionality that is accessible via plugins or other tools, but I would expect that to be very limited. See the bottom of the [IntelliJ IDEA features page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) for the way that JetBrains describes it:

[image: Screenshot from JetBrains site with Community vs Ultimate features]

When I create a new project in the Community Edition, I only see Gradle:

[image: New Project dialog for Community]

When I create a new project in the Ultimate Edition, I see Gradle and Grails 1/2 & Grails 3:

[image: New Project dialog for Ultimate]

You could [download the Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) and try it for free for up to 30 days, to make sure whether there is a difference in Grails support between both editions. If you like it, you can consider buying the Ultimate Edition ([free licenses](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/#section=discounts) are also available, for example for open source projects and educational use).

Comment: Grails 3 is Gradle based, which is supported out of the box by IntelliJ CE

Comment: Freek de Bruijn, thank you for your detailed response.  Debugging does indeed work.  Grails is now Spring Boot based and run by Gradle.  It has a regular ole runnable class, so it is no different than any other JVM application controlled by grade.  The Ultimate edition does have some benefits, but debugging is one of the basic things that can be done.